# What are the responsibilities of a project manager in a DevOps project?

Tags: project-management

A project in DevOps should logically change the management mechanisms.
What are the responsibilities of a project manager in a DevOps project ?

**Note**: A project DevOps of what I understand is a project that has a beginning and an end, it is a temporary effort to create a product or a unique result and that uses the concept DevOps to produce a software.

Comment: That just sounds like a software project to me. Can you clarify the distinction?

Comment: this is the link to this question at project mgmt SE but downvoted
https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/21883/what-are-the-responsibilities-of-a-project-manager-in-a-devops-project

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I mean Software project in a DEVOPS context

Answer (score 5):

Truth would be that should not happen in a DevOps environment
.
Your "project" will probably use Agile concepts, but there's nothing in DevOps telling how a project has to be run because DevOps is *[product centric](https://devopsguys.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/devops-and-the-product-centric-approach/)* (more details on the blog post and with search on this term).

"DevOps" is about breaking silos and have a team composed of developers, architects, ops, exploitation peoples who handle a software on its lifetime, that is antagonistic with the waterfall project approach.

To quote here Jez Humble:

> Products not projects

So your answer would be : There's not responsibilities for a project manager on a DevOps product because the main idea behind devops is to have a team handling the product on long term and not on a planned project time only.

Comment: Except maybe not go against the DevOps environment of the respective product just to get that particular project done :)

Comment: Usually if you form a project to change a devops managed product you break the engine running the product, just because you want to enforce a bunch of features in a counter productive way. The good approach should be to prioritize with the product owner the urgent features and keep the already running flow. Even a new product should not start in a project manner but should aim at building a team around the product with the business needs as a backlog IMHO